# Deleting app from appstore

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

I have submitted an app to appstore. It's approved and now ready for sale.

Now, I want to remove the app from appstore. How do I do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a way of actually removing an app from the appstore. But there is a way to remove it from sale:

Just click the "Rights and Pricing" button for your app and uncheck all appstore territories and afterwards click "Save Changes". Your app will then be no longer for sale.

Comment: Doing so, the application status changes to "Developer removed from sale", then we can see the "Delete application" button.

Answer (score 3):

Apple has changed the UI for this since I last tried it, the key part is that:

1. the option is hidden
2. the option that unhides the option is also hidden (argh!)

So, as moonbear pointed out, you have to manually deselect all territories ... but that option no longer exists (unless the app has been removed, in which case it DOES exist). So, the steps now are:

1. Select the app
2. Click the "rights and pricing" button
3. Inside the paragraph of text at bottom of screen is a linkified phrase "specific stores" (NB: unlike all the other options in iTunesConnect, this one is *not* a button)
4. ...which reveals the stores-list, and enables you to click "deselect all" button
5. With the new UI, you also have to select "starting from: NOW"
6. ...and "ending: NONE" (this is a new "feature" compared to last time - it's now compulsory)
7. Finally, click save
8. ...takes up to 2 hours for the iTunes servers to notice the change, so don't be surprised if your app still appears to be available
9. Go "back" (using itunes buttons, not the browser back button) to the App-page, where a new button has finally appeared: "Delete app"

9 steps to do something that used to be 2? Yikes. Not the best UI I've seen ...

Answer (score 2):

Go on itunes connect and there is an option there to remove your app from the appstore..Its detailed in the itunes connect manual here on page 86 [Itunes connect developer guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf)